# How I can short write coffeescript define

Tags: coffeescript

```
define ['a', 'b', 'c'], (A, B, C,) ->
```

I want write

```
define
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
   , (A, B, C,) ->
```

How to do it without a compiler error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define( 
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
  (A, B, C) -> 
    "D"
)
```

Which compiles to:

```
define(['a', 'b', 'c'], function(A, B, C) {
  return "D";
});
```

As a general rule, if you have multiple arguments that you want to be comma separated in the output but line separated in the input, put them at the same indent level.

The parentheses after the define are necessary to tell the compiler that there is a set of things that need to be passed into the function.

The comma after the `C` in your input was causing an error as well.

Comment: And what happens when you try to run that JavaScript? `f((a, b))` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I was trying to beat you so I didn't check that yet :/

Comment: Well, `f((a,b))` ends up evaluating `a` and calling `f(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get rid of the trailing comma in your anonymous function's argument list. Then you have a few options:

```
define \
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
  (A, B, C) ->
```

Be careful that the backslash doesn't have anything other than a newline after it. Or you could add parentheses:

```
define(
  ['a', 'b', 'c']
  (A, B, C) ->
)
```

but be very careful that you don't leave any space between `define` and `(` or you'll get an accidental [JavaScript comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in the JavaScript version.